# Type-C as a source and sink

Tags: voltage, pcb, usb, usb-c

I am designing a circuit that consists of Type-C male and female connectors. The device will act as a bridge between the mobile and the charger. I connected the CC1 and CC2 to 5.1k resistors on both connectors. My question is that when I connect the charger to my device while the device is still attached to the phone what will happen? Will the phone stop supplying power to the device and start working as a sink or still works as a source?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you came up with does not follow the USB C standard, so you get *undefined behavior*.

You need to use the USB PD protocol for communications. This means using a controller in combination with a USB C PD chip (could be on the same chip). You also need a protection mosfet so you keep the VBUS cold

You effectively want to make an USB C dock, which has an external power supply, incoming data from the mobile device and bi-direction power to the device.

The state flow is quite complex, for example, you need to implement a USB FRS to make sure USB communications are not interrupted if the charger is unplugged, you also need to read the USB C PD from the upstream charger, remove some part of it for the current device draw and its DC-DC converter and then send it back to the mobile.

Making an USB hub that support dock mode has too many variables for a simple resistor only connection method, so you are not going to see an working method with passives only

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense. Having 5.1k resistors on both the plug and the receptacle would mean that both devices are connected to a power requiring device and both phone and charge would give out 5 volts. It would be highly illegal situation and might damage the phone (or charger).

Comment: Both devices will connect to the source. First, the device will connect to the phone then the charger will connect to the device.

Comment: The device doesn't have any power source of its own.

Comment: Yes but by having 5k1 pull-downs on your device, it will request power from the phone and charger.

Comment: Yes, what is the solution without adding more components?

Comment: What do you want to do then? Have the phone providing power until a charger is plugged in so the charger both charges the phone and powers your device? There's no solution if no components can be added.

Comment: Okay, What should I do then?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve so I can't answer that. Adding suitable chips to handle USB-C PD negotiations between devices maybe?

Comment: The device will be connected to the phone as a sink. The device has a female plug where I want to connect the charger. I want the device to stop working as a sink when I connect the charger and work as a source for the cellphone.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that when I connect the charger to my device while the
> device is still attached to the phone what will happen?

The resistors are used for negotiation of the power and to let the other device know if it is a PD or PC. If you don't pass those through if the PD downstream from your hub needed a different power scheme other than the default, it would not be passed to the charger to negotiate a higher voltage. You would need some smarts to be able to pass these through and the hub would have to run on whatever power the device downstream needed.

Either that or you would have to have power circuitry on the hub that would be able to negotiate power with the PD.